# feel confuse on awk regular expression match digit [0-9]

Tags: regex, awk

I am very new to awk programming, I try to extract the process running time by

```
$ ps -o etime -p 18613 | awk /[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/
 1-00:05:52
```

I know if more than one day, it will in the format dd-hh:mm:ss, but I just feel confuse the regex /[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/ will also extract the "dd-", why not only show "00:05:52" in my result?

Comment: You should try using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) instead. Awk only passes/fails the whole line. It doesn't change the line's contents.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie ITYM that specific awk line only passes/fails the whole line. Of course you can write awk commands to select parts of lines just like you can in sed.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton - I haven't used either, so it was a guess on my part. Good to know though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon said in his comment on your question, `awk` when used this way just prints matching lines in their entirety.

For your particular case, I think it's sufficient to just print out the second line, minus the first three characters (that is, starting at the fourth character), which you can do like this:

```
ps -o etime -p 18613 | awk 'NR == 2 { print substr($0, 4); }'
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're trying to do with an RE:

```
ps -o etime -p 18613 |
awk 'match($0,/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/) { print substr($0,RTSTART,RLENGTH) }'
```

or in GNU awk if every line matches your RE:

```
ps -o etime -p 18613 |
awk '{print gensub(/.*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/,"\\1","") }'
```